# Common difficulty with Flex++

Tags: c++, lex, flex-lexer, flex++

Note: Someone with over 1500 rep.. please add flex++ and bison++ as tags :).

Seems like people all over the Internet have been getting the following errors with Flex++:

```
scanner.l:1: bad character: %
scanner.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
```

This happens on any example I give Flex++.  The version I have is from [here](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/index.php?page=20024) and I have tried the exact examples on that page and I still get these errors.  I've tried on Linux and Mac and have completely run out of ideas!

Seems like Flex++ is a name for an old virus out there too so it's particularly hard getting useful discussion!

EDIT:

Here's an example that produces the above error (first few lines from example taken from the link above):

```
%name CalcScanner
%define IOSTREAM
%define LEX_PARAM YY_CalcParser_STYPE *val, YY_CalcParser_LTYPE *loc
%define MEMBERS public: int line, column;                                                                                               
%define CONSTRUCTOR_INIT : line(1), column(1)

%header{
#include<sstream>
#include "parser.h"
%}
```

Any help would be more than fantastic.

EDIT 2: Please can people not edit this post by putting the 'flex' tag in?  Flex would be what I would use to tag but Flex is also an Adobe technology - it's NOT the tool I am using.  The flex tag on SO is for the Adobe product (hence the logo on the tag).  Thank you :).

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your example.

Comment: Just added some code to my post.  Thanks.

Comment: You're correct that `flex` is the wrong tag.  There's `gnu-flex` for the lexer/parser-generator.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I didn't see that tag.. added :).

Comment: @Ben: Which is an odd tag in itself; the flex we're talking about here is non-GNU. See http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/

Comment: @erik: Hey, I didn't create the tag.  Is there another flex application that is GNU?

Comment: @Ben: Haha, I know you didn't create it (well, technically, I didn't know that, but I assumed it); it was just a random observation, so to speak. And no, there is no GNU flex (at least not that I know of).

Answer (score 2):

Check your line-endings?  CR+LF vs NL might make a difference here.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately, doesn't seem to be the case.  Also, it complains about the very first character in the file which is confusing :s!

Comment: If the line endings were wrong, then flex++ would consider the entire file to be in line 1.  It could then be the second instance of `%` it's complaining about.  Can you put just the first line into a file by itself and see if the error messages are the same?

Comment: Thanks for the tips Ben.  Firstly, changing the line endings doesn't fix the problem...  I've tried both types by switching endings, saving as a new file and running it on the new file.  Putting the first line into a file of its own produces this:

Comment: `scanner2.l:1: bad character: %
scanner2.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
scanner2.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
scanner2.l:1: unknown error processing section 1
scanner2.l:1: premature EOF`